# Custom chained comparisons

Tags: python

Python allows expressions like `x > y > z`, which, according to the docs, is equivalent to `(x > y) and (y > z)` except `y` is only evaluated once. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

However, this seems to break if I customize comparison functions. E.g. suppose I have the following class: (Apologies for the large block, but once you read the `__eq__` method, the rest is trivial.)

```
class CompareList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "CompareList([" + ",".join(str(x) for x in self) + "])"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] == other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x == other for x in self)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] != other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x != other for x in self)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] > other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x > other for x in self)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] >= other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x >= other for x in self)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] < other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x < other for x in self)

    def __le__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] <= other[idx] for idx in xrange(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x <= other for x in self)
```

Now I can do fun stuff like `CompareList([10, 5]) > CompareList([5, 10])` and it will correctly return `CompareList([True,False])`

However, chaining these operations doesn't work nicely:

```
low = CompareList([1])
high = CompareList([2])
print(low > high > low) # returns CompareList([True])
```

Why not? What happens under the hood here? I know it isn't equivalent to `(low > high) > low` = `(False > low)` (because that would return False). It could be `low > (high > low)` but that wouldn't make sense in terms of operator precedence (normally left-to-right).

Comment: Check out `functools.total_ordering` - if I recall correctly, you only need to supply one cmp eg `__eq__` and one ordering, eg `__lt__` and add `@functools.total_ordering` to the **class**, and it should fill in the rest for you.

Comment: @dwanderson I remember reading Python would do the rest for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Python allows expressions like `x > y > z`, which, according to the docs, is equivalent to `(x > y) and (y > z)` except `y` is only evaluated once.

According to this, `low > high > low` will be equivalent to `(low > high) and (high > low)`.

```
>>> x = low > high   # CompareList([False])
>>> y = high > low   # CompareList([True]) 
>>> x and y
CompareList([True])
```

More from the documentation on [x and y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

> `x and y`:    if `x` is false, then `x`, else `y`

In the above case:

```
>>> x is False
False
>>> x if x is False else y     # x and y
CompareList([True])
```

so when you do `x and y` it returns the `y` which is `CompareList([True])`.

Comment: That... is a surprisingly simple answer!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "if `x` is falsy" with the code being either `if x` or `if bool(x) is False`? For example `'' and True` will return `''` despite `'' is not False`. Part of the issue here is that `bool(custom_object)` will return `True` unless `__nonzero__` is overridden, but filtering in the way OP intended is impossible, as noted in @iulian's answer.

Comment: `'' and True` returns `''` because [`bool('')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is `False`. so if you go by the logic `'' if '' is False else True` then `'' is False` evaluates to `True` and you get `''`.

Comment: In the above case also, `CompareList` is already inheriting from builtin `list`. And according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) on evaluating the `bool(some_obj)`, _ if the `__bool__` is not defined then `__len__` will be called. Since it is a `list` and it has one element which is `False` it will always return the length 1 and hence will never evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are right, but I wanted to address the actual <strike>lack of</strike> implementation for this problem, because, as I believe, what the OP would like to get as a result from `low > high > low` is a `CompareList([False])`.

Indeed, the `low > high > low` evaluates to `(low > high) and (high > low)` and since `CompareList([False]) is False` evaluates to `False` (which means that it is `True`), then the second operand of `and` operator gets evaluated and returned (as it also evaluates to `True`).

The key to implementing the chained comparison is to override the `and` boolean operator along `__gt__` and `__lt__`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this, and probably won't be. The [`PEP 335 - Overloadable Boolean Operators` proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) was rejected by Guido, but he might consider making chained comparisons like a < b < c overloadable [[1]](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-March/117510.html).

Unless that moment, there is no way to get your example to work as expected when using chained comparisons.

The only way to achieve the correct result is by overriding the `__and__` method and writing your comparisons like this:

```
def CompareList(list):
    ...
    def __and__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, list):
            return CompareList(self[idx] and other[idx] for idx in range(len(self)))
        else:
            return CompareList(x and other for x in self)
```

Then, by writing in the form below, you'll get the correct answer:

```
low = CompareList([1, 2])
high = CompareList([2, 2])
print((low >= high) & (high >= low)) # returns CompareList([False, True])
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't higher up, very insightful, especially the PEP reference. I would note that `CompareList([False]) is False` should probably be changed to `bool(CompareList([False])) is False` since its truthiness is being checked, not its identity.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thank you! I've posted it 1 hour after other answers were posted, so that's why...

Answer (score 1):

You should return a boolean value from your comparison methods.

To cite the [documentation for "rich comparison" methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> By convention, False and True are returned for a successful
>   comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the
>   comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the
>   condition of an if statement), Python will call bool() on the value to
>   determine if the result is true or false.

To break it down for this case:

```
exp1 = low > high
print(exp1)
print(bool(exp1))
exp2 = high > low
print(exp2)
print(bool(exp2))
```

Will give you

```
CompareList([False])
True
CompareList([True])
True
```

Now we do the last operation and print out the result

```
print(exp1 and exp2)
```

Because both values evaluate to `True` you'll get

```
CompareList([True])
```

Comment: I don't see how that has a relevance to the question of chaining comparisons. I'm aware that saying `if CompareList([True, False]):` doesn't make sense.

Comment: I added some more explanations.