# How to overload a double comparison in a custom class? (x < myobj < y)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a custom class which is some sort of data container. It is pretty straightforward to overload comparison operators as long as they are one at a time. But I can't find anywhere a solution for a double comparison. Consider this class:

```
class Custom:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return set([x for x in self.data if x > other])

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return set([x for x in self.data if x < other])
```

Then I do:

```
test = Custom(range(20))
print(test>5)
print(test<10)
```

and I get:

```
{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

as expected. However, when I do:

```
print(5<test<10)
```

I get

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

when I would expect the intersection (i.e. the equivalent to `(5  < test) & (test < 10)`):

```
{6, 7, 8, 9}
```

I thought that internally there would be two temporary results and that an `and (&)` operation would be performed on the two, but it seems that I get only the last result.

I tried creating a custom `class MySet(set)` that is used to return the output in the `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods, so instead the previous definition would change to something like

```
def __lt__(self, other):  # here, type(self) is Custom
    return MySet(set([x for x in self.data if x < other]))

# also analogous implementation for __gt__
```

where the new `MySet` also overloads the comparison methods, but these are never called.

(Note: for simplicity I have restricted the example to `<` and `>` but obviously the answer would extend to `<=` and `>=` too)

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: `and` is performed, however it is the **logical** `and` operator, not the bitwise `&` operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom chained comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140933/custom-chained-comparisons)

Comment: I think the problem is that your comparison operators return instances of `set` not your custom class

Comment: Wait, why do you expect the *intersection operator, `&` to be involved at all*??

Comment: After defining MySet, I have modified Custom to return MySet instead of set...

Comment: Well, when I say 'I expected' I mean that to me it made a lot of sense, since the operation performed as (test>5) & (test<10) works perfectly fine

Comment: No, `&` is the *bitwise and operator* , but chained comparisons use the *boolean and operator*, i.e `and`, hence why it's simply returning the first set, since it is truthy

Comment: OK, I see, in that case there's nothing to do. But, actually, what's funny about that last comment, is that it returns the second result, not the first, or view differently, apparently when doing ``5 < test < 10``, it performs the latter first (``test < 10``) since that is the result it returns...

Comment: Whoops, yes, my mistake. `and` returns the second value in the case both are truthy. It's all working as it should

Answer (score 2):

You can return `Custom` in your greater-than and lesser-than operators:

```py
class Custom:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return Custom({x for x in self.data if x > other})

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return Custom({x for x in self.data if x < other})
```

Only for debugging, you can also override the *repr* method:

```py
class Custom:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return Custom({x for x in self.data if x > other})

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return Custom({x for x in self.data if x < other})
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

The closer you can get to the behavior you want is using parenthesis:

```py
test = Custom(range(20))
print(test > 5)
# Outputs {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
print(test < 10)
# Outputs {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
print((5 < test) < 10)
# Outputs {8, 9, 6, 7}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems the best approach so far

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. `a < b < c` is shorthand for `a < b and b < c` and you can't customize `and`.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an alternative solution, which is in fact inspired by the one given by @enzo (thank you!) and by the suggested `MySet` in the original post. The reason is that in my real application, instantiating a `Custom` class has collateral consequences which for simplicity I didn't reflect here, and therefore I am reluctant to create extra instances of the `Custom` class everytime I am performing a comparison. I think I will go for the following:

```
import weakref as wk

class Custom:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return MySet(self, [x for x in self.data if x > other])

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return MySet(self, [x for x in self.data if x < other])


class MySet(set):

    def __init__(self, custom, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ref = wk.ref(custom)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self & (self.ref() > other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self & (self.ref() < other)


test = Custom(range(20))
print((5 < test) <10)
```

which indeed outputs:

```
{6, 7, 8, 9}
```